# mysql function to return set data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a stored procedure/function to return a set data type, but when I try, I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near 'return ('one');".  Any pointers?  This is the first time I've tried playing with stored procedures... Thanks!

```
delimiter //
create function getset (set_type enum('a','b','c'))
    returns set('one','two','three')
    deterministic
begin
  case set_type
    when 'a'
        return ('one');

    when 'b'
        return ('one,two');

    when 'c'
        return ('one,two,three');
end//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) is:

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

You're missing all the `THEN` keywords and `END CASE`. It should be:

```
  case set_type
    when 'a'
        then return ('one');

    when 'b'
        then return ('one,two');

    when 'c'
        then return ('one,two,three');

  end case;
```

The error message clearly says that the problem is near the `return` keyword. It has nothing to do with the data type, it's a syntax error.